# Google Play Developer Console Showing Alerts Even After Updating the Cordova Version

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, google-play-services, updates

Google Play is showing Cordova Security Alerts on my app. And they suggested me to update existing cordova version to higher at 4.1.1.

> Please migrate your app(s) to Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher as soon
>   as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK. If
>   you are using a 3rd party library that includes Apache Cordova, please
>   notify the 3rd party and work with them to address the issue.

I have already upgraded my Cordova version to: 4.2.0 and here is the code:

```
Mds-MacBook-Pro:BanglaGaanerTaroka Morol$ cordova -v
```

4.2.0
Mds-MacBook-Pro:BanglaGaanerTaroka Morol$

Google Play Developer console still showing this alert and that affected my latest APK version too.

Is there anyone facing the same issue? Or how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should understand that there is a cordova CLI version and cordova platform versions.
When google play ask you to update to cordova 4.1.1, he is not asking you to update the CLI to cordova 4.1.1, he is asking you to update the cordova android (platform) version to 4.1.1.

If you update the CLI to 4.2.0 you get cordova android 3.6.4 that is still vulnerable.

So, the first thing you should do is to update the cli to 6.0.0 (latest version right now) with

```
npm install -g cordova
```

But updating the CLI isn't enough, you have to update your project too.

Go to your project folder and run

```
cordova platform update android
```

That will update your project to Cordova Android: ~5.1.0

Comment: I see my Cordova Version is 6.0.0 (Following this command: npm view cordova version) and CLI version is 4.2.0 (cordova -v). I shouldn't have any problem...right? But it is still showing me the same error!

Comment: No, you have to update your cordova android version of your project. Go to your project folder and type ```cordova platform list``` it will show you your platforms versions